# How to write to file a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have the following tuple of dictionaries:

```
myListOfDict = {
'READ_NAME': 'NB501050:52:HHMJJBGXY:4:13609:11402:8330', 'CLASS_ID': 3, 'SEQ_ID': 0, 'READ_LEN': 136, 'QVALUES': 'KEOLFC.I?EA;CHEJ?/0CGDBI1GF4D+>-CEB8/J/EFF=HK/0GGGHCFG;GFBH0JG8GG..DGH/BKD?,BHFCFHKF=BH-HFG3BHHGGHFHIBGHFHKDIIJCFGHABGIEHCFFHFHEHEEGQOOO', 'SEQUENCE': 'CACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCCCTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATT', 'MAPPING_POS': 3, 'DELTA': 0, 'ECIGAR_STRING': '24=C111=', 'ECIGAR_LEN': 8, 'REVERSE_COMP': 1, 'MAPPING_SCORE': 70.0
}, 
{
'READ_NAME': 'NB501050:47:HHMJVBGXY:2:11311:23488:9633', 'CLASS_ID': 3, 'SEQ_ID': 0, 'READ_LEN': 136, 'QVALUES': 'K@KJ<E12I1H0I@BGGHFIJFHFIKFCIKFGGGGH=EGG@FBHFJGGGGG0HGHDEKDBIBHFCFIKFGFHBHFHDBIJGGHFEIBGHFIKDIIJCFGHFBIKFHCFF5GHFIGDGGEFEHJFI6JEJEEHRKMN', 'SEQUENCE': 'CTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTCATCCTAT', 'MAPPING_POS': 18, 'DELTA': 0, 'ECIGAR_STRING': '131=C4=', 'ECIGAR_LEN': 7, 'REVERSE_COMP': 1, 'MAPPING_SCORE': 70.0
}, 
{...}
```

For each element of the tuple (that is a dictionary), I need to print to a file ONLY the value corresponding to each key. Below what I'm looking for:

```
NB501050:52:HHMJJBGXY:4:13609:11402:8330 3 0 136 KEOLFC.I?EA;CHEJ?/0CGDBI1GF4D+>-CEB8/J/EFF=HK/0GGGHCFG;GFBH0JG8GG..DGH/BKD?,BHFCFHKF=BH HFG3BHHGGHFHIBGHFHKDIIJCFGHABGIEHCFFHFHEHEEGQOOO ..
NB501050:47:HHMJVBGXY:2:11311:23488:9633 3 0 136 K@KJ<E12I1H0I@BGGHFIJFHFIKFCIKFGGGGH=EGG@FBHFJGGGGG0HGHDEKDBIBHFCFIKFGFHBHFHDBIJGGHFEIBGHFIKDIIJCFGHFBIKFHCFF5GHFIGDGGEFEHJFI6JEJEEHRKMN ...
```

I implemented the following code:

```
with open("filename_t", "w") as f:
 for val in myListOfDict:
    for val1 in val.items():
        for val2 in val1:
           f.write(str(val2) + "  ")
    f.write("\n")
```

but I don't get what I want..

```
READ_NAME  NB501050:52:HHMJJBGXY:4:13609:11402:8330  CLASS_ID  3  SEQ_ID  0 READ_LEN  136  QVALUES  KEOLFC.I?EA;CHEJ?/0CGDBI1GF4D+>-CEB8/J/EFF=HK/0GGGHCFG;GFBH0JG8GG..DGH/BKD?,BHFCFHKF=BH-HFG3BHHGGHFHIBGHFHKDIIJCFGHABGIEHCFFHFHEHEEGQOOO  SEQUENCE  CACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCCCTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATT  MAPPING_POS  3  DELTA  0  ECIGAR_STRING  24=C111=  ECIGAR_LEN  8  REVERSE_COMP  1  MAPPING_SCORE  70.0  
READ_NAME  NB501050:47:HHMJVBGXY:2:11311:23488:9633  CLASS_ID  3  SEQ_ID  0 READ_LEN  136  QVALUES  K@KJ<E12I1H0I@BGGHFIJFHFIKFCIKFGGGGH=EGG@FBHFJGGGGG0HGHDEKDBIBHFCFIKFGFHBHFHDBIJGGHFEIBGHFIKDIIJCFGHFBIKFHCFF5GHFIGDGGEFEHJFI6JEJEEHRKMN  SEQUENCE  CTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTCATCCTAT  MAPPING_POS  18  DELTA  0  ECIGAR_STRING  131=C4=  ECIGAR_LEN  7  REVERSE_COMP  1  MAPPING_SCORE  70.0
```

How can I avoid printing the keys?

Comment: your expected output looks like `csv` file with space as separtor (instead of comma) so you could try to use `csv.DictWriter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing both keys and values because you are using `dict.items()` function which returns key-value tuples. Just change your code to:

```
with open("filename_t", "w") as f:
 for val in myListOfDict:
    for val1 in val.values():
        f.write(str(val1) + "  ")
    f.write("\n")
```

---

Note that dictionary doesn't guarantee you the keys/values/items order.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting what I need! 
"Note that dictionary doesn't guarantee you the keys/values/items order." 
I checked and so far I'm getting the expected output..

Comment: @user123892, The "solution" outputs '[0, 0, 0]' for value [0, 0, 0] where it seems what you wanted was '0 0 0'. So either the solution is not quite correct or you did not state what you wanted correctly.

Comment: Ah right, 'FLAGS': [0, 0, 0] is a list itself. I'm testing this piece of code on a test-list, the real one wont have such case. I edit my question and delete that entry. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

myListOfDict = [{
'READ_NAME': 'NB501050:52:HHMJJBGXY:4:13609:11402:8330', 'CLASS_ID': 3, 'SEQ_ID': 0, 'FLAGS': [0, 0, 0], 'READ_LEN': 136, 'QVALUES': 'KEOLFC.I?EA;CHEJ?/0CGDBI1GF4D+>-CEB8/J/EFF=HK/0GGGHCFG;GFBH0JG8GG..DGH/BKD?,BHFCFHKF=BH-HFG3BHHGGHFHIBGHFHKDIIJCFGHABGIEHCFFHFHEHEEGQOOO', 'SEQUENCE': 'CACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCCCTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATT', 'MAPPING_POS': 3, 'DELTA': 0, 'ECIGAR_STRING': '24=C111=', 'ECIGAR_LEN': 8, 'REVERSE_COMP': 1, 'MAPPING_SCORE': 70.0
}]

with open("filename_t", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=" ", fieldnames=['REVERSE_COMP', 'SEQUENCE', 'CLASS_ID', 'SEQ_ID', 'READ_LEN', 'ECIGAR_LEN', 'FLAGS', 'MAPPING_SCORE', 'ECIGAR_STRING', 'MAPPING_POS', 'QVALUES', 'READ_NAME', 'DELTA'])
    for val in myListOfDict:
        writer.writerow(val)
```

Comment: thank you, I've solved the issue by implementing @vurmux solution. I will try also yours later on.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("filename_t", "w") as f:
    for val in myListOfDict:
        for val1 in val.values():
            if isinstance(val1, list):
                v = ' '.join(map(lambda x: str(x), val1))
            else:
                v = str(val1)
            f.write(v + "  ")
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: I will keep your solution in mind when I will need to process key:list[]. 
Thank you!!